# Why is pip3 throwing error while installing packages?

Tags: python, pip

I am using Kubuntu.

I can not install any package using pip.I uninstalled pip and reinstalled it restarted my computer, internet connection, terminal. But the problem remains the same.My internet connection has no issue.

It would be very helpful if you guys can give step by step solution.

```
samip@samip-Inspiron-3521:~$ pip3 install pygame

Collecting pygame
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
 /packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-
1.9.6.tar.gz (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', 
port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))
```

Comment: Check if you have a stable internet connection and then try  `pip3 install pygame --user`

Answer (score 1):

As Nomi Shaw suggested, your problem seems to be a weak internet connection.

Also, please do not install third party packages into the global python interpreter by directly using pip or pip3.

Please, create and activate a virtual environment first.

RealPython.com has an excellent article about the why and the how:

https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: I generally install third party packages in virtual environment this time i was only trying to show the problem and my internet is not a problem it is working perfectly fine I can watch youtube videos in HD download movies and do other stuff in my laptop and other devices but I can not install any packages using pip.

Comment: You could use traceroute to debug your connection problems. Or try to use wget/curl to get the files. There could be DNS problems. There also could be problems using SSL. Unfortunately, there could be so many different reasons. You have to narrow down the problem. (Maybe you work behind a firewall? ...)

Comment: or perhaps pygame was having network issues
you could try installing the package from source
https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Nomi Shaw and jugmac00 said, I had the same problem a couple of months back and it drove me crazy. I don't know how likely it is that you're experiencing the same problem but just in case:

My errors were caused by an internet filter I installed ([Pluckeye](https://www.pluckeye.net/)) that it turns out was blocking not only my browser connections but all my other connections too (pip, calibre, r...). Once I set it to a lower level of restriction everything worked fine!

Comment: Can you please provide more info about your solution.